# Error 503: Service Unavailable by magento2

Tags: magento2

I've faced a problem after unsuccessful install of a module from magento2 connect. My platform is windows8-apache2.2-php5.6-mysql5.6, Open the home page appears as follows:

Service Temporarily Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Please help me!thanks.

Comment: maintence.flag file exist in your root folder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's solved.
Delete the file called `.maintenance.flag` located in the `var` folder. Then appear

> Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons

and check the error log, the error log prompt

> Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory

and execute this command in the GIT root directory.